# jQuery Not Rearranging Elements on my Django Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I'm trying to add 2 sort options to a web page. Currently, when I click the respective links (.alpha and .finish), I see an animation on the screen and can tell that the names are moving, but then the output remains the same. Below is the jQuery script I'm working with off of this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hibbard_eu/C2heg/) that I found in a google search.

```
var $divs = $('div.col-xs-3');
$('.alpha').on('click', function () {
    var alphabeticallyOrderedDivs = $divs.sort(function (a, b) {
        return $(a).attr('data-name') > $(b).attr('data-name');
    });
    $('.people').html(alphabeticallyOrderedDivs);
});

$('.finish').on('click', function () {
    var numericallyOrderedDivs = $divs.sort(function (a, b) {
        return $(a).attr('id') < $(b).attr('id');
    });
    $('.people').html(numericallyOrderedDivs);
});
```

I am using Django to display the page and currently have an order_by to correctly order each div alphabetically. Is this affecting it?

Comment: What's wrong on JSFiddle? It seems to work, I can see the elements sorted in the proper way and they persist. Maybe you should post some other parts of the code you're writing

Comment: I found that JSFiddle and I am using it as a reference. It shows what I want to do but it is not my actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Three things:

1. jQuery doesn't officially have a `sort` function, so don't rely on it.
2. The sort function it does have (unofficially) it gets from `Array.prototype`. We'll use that one directly. The way that sort function's callback works, it's expected to return a **number**, not a boolean: A negative number if the first argument should appear before the second, 0 if they're equal for sorting purposes, and greater than zero if the second should appear before the first.
3. Officially, [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) doesn't accept either a jQuery object or an array (just strings and functions), so let's use `empty().append(...)` instead:

So to fix the code in your question, first we use `get` to get a true array from the jQuery set, and then we use `localeCompare` to correctly compare the names:

```js
var $divs = $('div.col-xs-3');
$('.alpha').on('click', function () {
    var alphabeticallyOrderedDivs = $divs.get().sort(function (a, b) {
    // Note -----------------------------^^^^^^
        return $(a).attr('data-name').localeCompare($(b).attr('data-name'));
    // Note -------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    });
    $('.people').empty().append(alphabeticallyOrderedDivs);
    // Note -----^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
});
```

```html
<input type="button" class="alpha" value="Alpha">
  <div class="people">
  <div class="col-xs-3" data-name="q">q</div>
  <div class="col-xs-3" data-name="p">p</div>
  <div class="col-xs-3" data-name="j">j</div>
  <div class="col-xs-3" data-name="e">e</div>
  <div class="col-xs-3" data-name="t">t</div>
  <div class="col-xs-3" data-name="d">e</div>
  <div class="col-xs-3" data-name="a">a</div>
  <div class="col-xs-3" data-name="q">q</div>
  <div class="col-xs-3" data-name="r">r</div>
  <div class="col-xs-3" data-name="x">x</div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight. New to jQuery, so when I found something that worked in a google search, I just went with it. I've implemented the changes you suggested but nothing is happening now. Before I saw some animation before but now I'm not seeing anything.

Comment: @SepticReVo: The above works, so there must be some issue with how you applied it to your code. I've updated the answer to demonstrate it working.

Comment: Maybe it's because I am using an order_by in my Django view? Would the script for a numerical sort look like this? `$('.finish').on('click', function () {
        var numericallyOrderedDivs = $divs.get().sort(function (a, b) {
            return $(a).attr('data-id').localeCompare($(b).attr('data-id'));
        });
        $('.people').empty.append(numericallyOrderedDivs);
    });`

Comment: @SepticReVo: No, `localeCompare` is for strings. If the attributes contain just digits, you can safely rely on implicit coercion and use `return $(a).attr("data-id") - $(b).attr("data-id");` (Sorry, know nothing about Django.)